# Laravel Guzzle Parse XML Response

Tags: php, xml, laravel, guzzle

I'm pretty new to using Laravel (5.1)/PHP and especially doing anything with the Guzzle HTTP package. I have an api I'm trying to return a response from. I'm successfully getting the response, but I need to save pieces of it to variables to use later in my applicaiton

How do I parse through the response to get the pieces of xml that I need, say anything within `<status>Passing</status>`?

The following retrieves the entire xml response.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.com?parameter=value');
$body = $res->getBody();
echo $body;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with Guzzle but try this.

```
$xml = $response->xml();
$status = $xml->status;
```

Here's the documentation from which I based this off of:

http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/response.html#xml-responses

Comment: I should have added I'm using the latest version of Guzzle (6) and the xml method you specified is not included. :-(

Comment: $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
  $response = $client->request('GET', 'yourURL');
  $response = $response->getBody()->getContents();
  return $response;